# Unnecessary drop down events fire in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have these drop downs in my application

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" DataTextField="Val" DataValueField="ValID" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1change"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" DataTextField="Val" DataValueField="ValID" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1change"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl3" runat="server" DataTextField="Val" DataValueField="ValID" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1change"></asp:DropDownList>
```

This is the OnSelectedIndexChanged function in the cs page

```
 protected void ddl1change(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DropDownList ddltemp = sender as DropDownList;

            if (ddltemp.SelectedItem.Text != "---Select---")
            {
                selectedltrDropdownText = ddltemp.SelectedItem.Text;                    
                PassFileName(selectedltrDropdownText);                    
            }           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("Failed." + ex.Message + "; Stack Trace :" + ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }
```

This is how I load the drop down

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (!IsPostBack)
         {
               Fill();
         }
    }
```

The Fill(); Gets some types which needs to be loaded in the drop down.

My problem:

First step : I am changing the ddl1 everything works fine.
Second step: I am changing the ddl2 , now the event fires for both ddl1 and ddl2. But only ddl2 needs to be fired on this case.
I don't have any clue why ddl1 fires in this case. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong or what should I do?

Comment: OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1change" is same for all 3 dropdowns. So which ever ddl you change, the event will be same.

Comment: How do you confirm that the event is firing for both ddls second time?

Comment: That's not what I am looking for and I know that events will be same . Kindly read my question and code properly. Thanks

Comment: You have to create separate  OnSelectedIndexChanged event for each dropdown in order to prevent changes on other dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you set OnSelectedIndexChanged for all three dropdownlists to ddl1change. Once the method is fired, the value in ddl1 is changed. Hence, it triggers the postback.
[image]

Comment: I am trying Something like this in the drop down change event, When drop down is changed I am getting the text selected in the drop down and sending it to a function as shown in the above coding. So i thought of having a single function. Can I achieve this functionality using a single function?

Answer (score -1):

In your code AutoPost back is True. so you are facing this problem

Comment: Change OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1change" with different names. like